# How to deal with JSON Objects and JSON Arrays using the New York Times API in Processing

Tags: arrays, json, processing

I am trying to save data being returned from the New York Times into one array.  For each page of results, The New York Times API returns a new array with 10 objects.  As a result, `JSONArray results`is just a collection of multiple arrays.  This makes it difficult for me to `saveJSONArray results` because it only saves ONE of the arrays (with 10 objets inside of it).  What is the best solution?  How do I parse all the JSONObjects into one array?  Thanks!

```
String baseURL = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article";
String apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:x:xxxxxx";


size(500, 300);


String beginDate = "19940101";
String endDate = "19960101";
String word = "O.J.+Simpson";

for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  String request = baseURL + "?query=" + word + "&begin_date=" + beginDate + "&end_date=" + endDate + "&offset=" + i + "&api-key=" + apiKey;
  i = i + 1;
  String result = join(loadStrings(request), "");
  JSONObject nytData = JSONObject.parse(result);

  JSONArray results = nytData.getJSONArray("results");

  //saveJSONArray(results, "data/new.json");  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously, saveJSONArray does not append to file thus it just overwrites it each time with the last batch of 10 items. You have to gather the results and then save them in a file like this:

```
JSONArray results = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  String request = baseURL + "?query=" + word + "&begin_date=" + beginDate + "&end_date=" + endDate + "&offset=" + i + "&api-key=" + apiKey;
  i = i + 1;
  String result = join(loadStrings(request), "");
  JSONObject nytData = JSONObject.parse(result);

  JSONArray newData = nytData.getJSONArray("results");
  for(int j = 0; j < newData.size(); j++) 
  results.append(newData.getJSONObject(j));
  //println(results);
}
  saveJSONArray(results, "data/new.json");
```

which will produce a file with internal structure of a JSONArray with JSONObjects in like this:

```
[ { object from batch 1}, { object from batch 1}, { object from batch 2 } ]
```

or, if want to keep the 10-item encapsulation, instead of the nested for loop use:

```
results.append(nytData.getJSONArray("results"));
```

which will yield results as JSONObjects in JSONArrays in JSONArrays like this:

```
[ [ { object from batch 1}, { object from batch 1} ],[ { object from batch 2 } ] ]
```